# How to fix 500 server error? and how to login to WordPress dashboard?

Tags: php, wordpress, server-error, google-advertising-id

I had pasted an google  add sense code in WordPress by following steps:

**step 1**

login to my dashboard , then I go to appearance tab & select editor option

**step 2**

after that I go to the theme-functions , a window open having code.

**step 3**

I go to the last of this window then hit enter and place the add code by google adsense adunit.

Code is:

```
Function myAddSenseFunction(){
return '<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- header ad -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-6517659835455449"
     data-ad-slot="7383706018"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>';
}
add_shortcode('addToAppearHere','myAddSenseFunction')
```

after it i update file

then my word press admin panel did not open. a 500 server error message occurred. 
please suggest me how to fix this error ? and login to again my dashboard ??

Comment: Please add the code as it looks like it did not get pasted in.

Comment: You need to actually include the code.  Also, a 500 error means something went wrong server-side.  There should be server-side logs or error reporting somewhere, no?

Comment: @David maybe he does not remember his code what he added because he can not access his dashboard right now because of 500 error.

Comment: @Dingling: If he can't access his code, how is he going to fix it?  Not being able to view/edit the code is a more significant problem that would need to be solved before attempting to apply any fix to that code.

Comment: @David can he use filezila to access the server and recode that file? will this work in this situation?

Comment: @Dingling: I don't know, the OP should really know how to access the source code.  Locking oneself out of one's own property isn't really a code problem :-/

Comment: @David: OP? i think problem came when he changed the default code by attempting to insert ad function. and only way this problem is going to resolve when he access that file and find the coding error or just remove the changes he done. but wordpress is not allowing him, for this reason he need to access file via filezilla ftp server and replace the correction it it, am i right?

Comment: @Dingling: I would certainly think so.  If the files need to be changed then *being able to access the files* is a good step toward accomplishing that.  If the OP is instead only accessing code through some running application (a web interface) which itself is susceptible to being broken by one's own code then that seems like a problem waiting to happen.

Comment: @saba luqman: you forgot to add ';' semicolon in last line of code.

Comment: @David: then what's the possible way to access source code?

Comment: @Dingling: I don't know.  I don't own or manage the OP's code.  If it were *my* code then it would be in a source control system of some kind.  A failed/broken deployment to the target environment would be corrected by re-deploying the previous version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you wanted to add your **google adsense ad unit** in your wordpress blog. And when you wanted to **place ad in your post**.

> For that purpose you logged in into your wp-admin dashboard and your
>   changed your theme by adding a function into `function.php` file within
>   the theme-functions option. You must have to put your function
>   (containing ad unit code) at the end of the file and updated it. Then
>   you can use your function name in your post like `[functionName]` and
>   that's how you place ad in your wordpress post.

But you messed up your site, and **`getting 500 server error`** its mean function you have added in wordpress file is having a **programming error**.

> That's why you can't even access your wp-admin dashboard, do you also have
>   problem accessing that post in which you added your ad?

And now you want a solution **somehow to check that file function.php** and **resolve that error**. And you want your site to not give 500 server error.

Comment: thanks Dingling for understanding the problem. it was actually i did that u write. but how to access the function.php file. whenever i tried to load the wordpress admin it gives server error 500